# SQL - Getting students who passed in all subjects

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a database table with some fields and sample records as shown below:

```
Name    Test    Result  Other_fields  
A      English    P         x  
B      Maths      F         x  
C      English    P         x  
B      English    P         x  
A      Maths      F         x  
D      English    P         x  
C      Biology    F         x  
A      Biology    P         x  
B      Biology    F         x
```

Now the actual table contains a lot more variety of tests.
What I want to achieve is find count/list of students(and the corresponding values in other fields which are unique for a student...say his age, sex etc.) who passed in all the tests specified in a **comma-separated string**. The string obviously is inserted into query at run-time.

Now if it were a fixed number of tests say 2 tests or 3 tests then I could write a query for it.
But the real problem is number of tests in the CSV string is not fixed.
Is there any way I could achieve this?

PS: I am okay to substitute test name with some unique number(to function as test ID) if one plans to suggest an answer involving use of SQL IN.

**EDIT**

Apparently, I did not make myself quite clear. The table will contain records for a large number of tests(say test1, test2,....test100). The CSV string will contain a few of those tests(say 2 or 3 or 4 but definitely more than 1). And I want the data where student passed in all the tests specified by CSV string.

**EDIT 2**
There can be multiple records corresponding to one combination of a student and a test(multiple times pass and fail)

Comment: Where did you get the CSV string from?  What happens if a test has a comma in the name? You should avoid encoding this in a CSV string.  If that's not possible, you should parse it before you try to query Oracle with it.

Comment: Can user take one test multiple times? If yes, then should the student be included in the result if he has failed at least once? If you have tests to pass in a separate table and you need to check if student has passed each of those tests at least once, then the solution is very simple join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name 
  FROM Table t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM Table 
                   WHERE     t.Name = Name 
                         AND Result = 'F'
                         AND ',' || CsvOfTests || ',' LIKE '%,' || Test || ',%'
                 )
```

I would recommend using some unique value like auto-incremented id instead of the name here. If you want to have additional fields in the result set you can include them in your SELECT and GROUP BY field list or by using a join.

CsvOfTests is the list of tests that you are interested of. I added commas to the beginning and the end of the CsvOfTests and Test in case name of one test is the substring of the name of some other test. 
However I have to say that I feel that the query would be much simpler and less hacky if you would put the tests into temporary table instead of csv string.

If your input string separates tests by more than just a comma (like with a space after a comma you will need include those aswell). If it's more complicated than that then I guess I'd try REGEXP_LIKE or write my own function.

Per request the query that counts passed subjects

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name 
  FROM Table t
 WHERE LENGTH(CsvOfTests) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CsvOfTests, ',')) + 1 = (
                  SELECT COUNT(1)
                    FROM Table 
                   WHERE     t.Name = Name 
                         AND Result = 'P'
                         AND ',' || CsvOfTests || ',' LIKE '%,' || Test || ',%'
                 )
```

Here `LENGTH(CsvOfTests) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CsvOfTests, ',')) + 1` counts the number of tests in your list. Then it justs counts how many of those tests the student has passed. Apparently there's also [REGEXP_COUNT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm) to do the same in 11g Release 1.

After I reread and thought about your question, I understood that this was not exactly that you were asking for. The goal of this query more on the line of checking whether student has passed each subject (i.e. if you fail the exam the first time then you retake it and eventually pass).

Comment: I don't want it for all the test....only the tests specified by a CSV string....its ok if student has failed in other tests...I guess I did not make it clear....my apologies

Comment: I will have to test this before I can say anything..I am indeed planning to use unique test IDs instead of test names...No....I have already taken care that it will be comma-separated..

Comment: Would this work if there are multiple attempts by a person for a subject?

Comment: It would. Also, notice that I have simplified the query a little.

Comment: Oh thanks. I will test this asap..Can you post your old query involving counting subjects from CSV string as well? I may even consider that..

Comment: Sure, if you think it's useful.

Comment: I believe I can replace AND ',' || CsvOfTests || ',' LIKE '%,' || Test || ',%' with INSTR(CSVofTests,Test)<>0 for better performance. What do you think? Because as of now, the query is crawling(My db has records for a loooot of students)

Comment: If you try INSTR then make sure you still have to add commas to the beginning and to the end of both Test and CsvOfTests. I'm not sure if it improves performance, but let me know if it does.

Comment: Its still crawling...
So, I am considering your suggestion of storing the subject IDs in separate temporary table and then somehow get this done....hmmm....I need to think...you have any suggestion?

Comment: Make sure you have the table properly indexed. If you have a lot of students then you need to have at least Name column indexed (or preferably StudentId instead of Name).

Comment: I ended up restricting number of tests to 5 and use 4 inner joins because thats faster..
thanks for all the help and ideas though..

Answer (score 1):

You want to look for how to turn a csv into a table.  I've never done this for Oracle, but it should be fairly easy to do.

Alternatively, consider whether you really need to send a csv, or could you send multiple parameters.  Something like `Test in (param1,param2,....paramX)`.  If you allow a limited number of parameters, this is viable.  It of course won't work if you are sending thousands of parameters, imo a dozen is pushing it, but if you are always sending like 3-5, it works just fine.

Edit: Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b977f/19) that shows basically what I mean and how to do it.  It splits a string, joins the string, counts the number of matching test, and list the student/test information where the student passed all of the incoming test.  My original example had a join on 1=1 because I was having a trouble with column names and I wanted to show the join happening.

```
With t as (
Select 'English, Biology' as Tests from dual
),
Spl as(
Select rtrim(ltrim(REGEXP_SUBSTR (Tests, '[^,]+', 1, level))) As Tst,
 regexp_count(Tests,'[,]')+1 NumberOfTest
from t
connect by level<= regexp_count(Tests,'[,]')+1
)
, StudentPassing as (
Select count(TestName) over (partition by StudentName) TestPassed, 
    s.*, NumberOfTest
from StudentTest s 
  inner join Spl 
    on Tst=TestName
where TestResult='P'
)
select *
from StudentPassing
where TestPassed=NumberOfTest
```

Comment: I am not sure I am following what you are trying to say by multiple parameters....they all are in a single field in DB..

Comment: I am going to think about your first suggestion..How do you suggest I go about it then(I know how to create a table from CSV string)..

Comment: Once you have a table of test they have to have taken nd past, simply join on that and then do you counting/distinct values.

Comment: Can you explain the later part...what do I do after the inner join...I am not sure if simply counting the student IDs will give me desired results because the inner join is for 1=1...